# The delegate pattern does not fire in the class where it is implemented

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, delegates, protocols

There is a TopMenuBar class. This is a menu bar (collectionView) for a tableViewCell in the main class (named - MainVC).

```
class TopMenuBar: UITableViewCell {
     public var delegate: TopMenuBarDelegate?
}
```

and protocol:

```
protocol TopMenuBarDelegate {
     func didTapTopMenuCell(named: String)
}
```

In the didSelectItemAt() method with delegate, I call this protocol:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
     ///Relay to delegate about menu item selection
    let selectedItem = menuItems[indexPath.row + 1].description
    delegate?.didTapTopMenuCell(named: selectedItem)
}
```

Further, in the main class - MainVC, I subscribed to the protocol - TopMenuBarDelegate, added a protocol method - didTapTopMenuCell(), created an instance of the TopMenuBar class and in the viewDidLoad method I assigned a delegate to this protocol - the MainVC class.

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, TopMenuBarDelegate {

   let topMenuBar = TopMenuBar()

   func didTapTopMenuCell(named: String) {
       print(named)
   }
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   topMenuBar.delegate = self
   }
}
```

To test the functionality, I only want to print the name of the cell that I clicked on.
As a result, nothing appears in the console.

Comment: How does the `TopMenuBar` get presented onto the screen?  Is it the same instance of that class that you're injecting the delegate into?

Comment: @PhillipMills It is a separate collectionview class for my menu bar. In the MainVC class, it is represented as a headerView in tableView. As menu in a table))

Comment: Is `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView` inside `TopMenuBar` or `MainVC`?

Comment: @aheze collection method inside TopMenuBar.

Comment: Hmm... can you confirm that the method is actually getting called?

Comment: @aheze This is the crux of the matter - method 'func didTapTopMenuCell(named: String)' in MainVC doesn't work. There is no communication between the classes.

Comment: You are not declaring the following line at the right place.  `topMenuBar.delegate = self`

Comment: @PAULMAX what about `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView`? Can you also `print(delegate)` to see if it's nil or not?

Comment: @ElTomato How did your comment help solve my problem?

Comment: @aheze It's nil...

Comment: @PAULMAX can you show code for `addSubview(topMenuBar)` or where you are displaying it? You might have accidentally created a new instance

Comment: @aheze TopMenuBar is a class TopMenuBar: UITableViewCell {...}
In other words it's a cell for headerView in table of MainVC.
this cell stores or creates a Collection View and further - 'func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: TopMenuBar.cellIdentifier()) as? TopMenuBar else {
                return nil
        }
        return cell
    }'

Comment: @PAULMAX yup, seems like you created a new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using your `topMenuBar`.

```
let topMenuBar = TopMenuBar()
```

In `viewDidLoad` you do `topMenuBar.delegate = self`, but the ***actual*** view that you set as the header is this:

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TopMenuBar.cellIdentifier()) as? TopMenuBar else {
    return nil
}
```

Here, you're creating a new `TopMenuBar` (`cell`)! You're not using the `let topMenuBar = TopMenuBar()` at all!

What you need to do is get rid of:

```
let topMenuBar = TopMenuBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    topMenuBar.delegate = self
}
```

and instead, set the delegate of `cell`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TopMenuBar.cellIdentifier()) as? TopMenuBar else {
        return nil
    }

    cell.delegate = self /// assign here!
    return cell
}
```

Comment: it was a mega super cool decision!!!
I did it differently here - topMenuBar.delegate = self.
I don't understand yet - cell.delegate = self.
I need to figure out how it works under the hood.
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @PAULMAX you created 2 different examples of TopMenuBar, you assign delegate to the first and call as cell the second. That's why nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than placing the topMenuBar.delegate = self in the viewDidLoad, try putting it in the cellForItemAt when you initialize the collectionView in the MainVC.

Comment: Collectionview is a cell (header )in a tableView in MainVC. 
Should i do it in this method?
'code' func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?